# Где лежит child_process.js?

Tags: linux, node.js

Привет, All!

при работе с unoconv появилась ошибка:

```
child_process.js:961
throw new TypeError('options argument must be an object');
```

где можно увидеть код этого файла?

поиск наше созвучные файлы, но там всего по 300 строк, 961 нет

Спасибо

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973116/where-is-child-process-js

Comment: да, спасибо, видел эту ссылку, но у меня в ошибке строка 961, а в той ссылке, на этом месте другое сообщение, мое же находится 970, значит файлы различаются

Answer (score 1):

всем спасибо, решил свою проблему, в текущей версии nodejs (v0.12) был изменен вызов функции child_process.spawn(/*file, args, options, callback*/), появился параметр options, в результате старые модули (например https://github.com/gfloyd/node-unoconv) работают не корректно

Answer (score 0):

Если это не какой-то свой файл так обозванный, то в архиве с node.js (если остался) файл ./lib/child_process.js.
А вообще Вы просто передаете неверные параметры в функцию из него

> 'options argument must be an object'

как бы намекает, что в качестве аргумента с названием *options* необходимо передавать объект

update: хм, коментария перед правкой не видел)

Comment: я понимаю суть ошибки, но ошибка возникает в этом модуле
https://github.com/gfloyd/node-unoconv
он в свою очередь вызывает child_process.js

я хотел посмотреть какие аргументы приходят в child_process.js

к сожалению в ./lib такого файла нет